# " org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Collection not found" when connecting solr 5.5 using solrj 4.x

Tags: solr, solrj, solr5

Below is the code I am trying

```
    String zkHostString = "zookeepername";  
    CloudSolrServer cloudSolrServer=new CloudSolrServer(zkHostString);  
    cloudSolrServer.setDefaultCollection("collectionname");  
    SolrPingResponse ping = cloudSolrServer.ping();  
    System.out.println("ping -->"+ping);  
    SolrPingResponse rsp=new SolrPingResponse();
```

Comment: Well, does the collection exist? You can check this at your Solr admin page.

Comment: @MatsLindh  Yes. The collection exist. When we use solrj5.x the ping is returning results. But solrj4.X is not returning

Comment: My guess is that the format of the clusterstate in zookeeper has changed between 4.x and 5.x, so SolrJ 4.x isn't able to determine which collections exists based on the 5.x format.

Comment: @MatsLindh Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: You'd probably have to dig into the source of SolrJ 4 vs SolrJ 5 and create your own version of SolrJ in that case - I'd rather just upgrade to the most recent version of SolrJ - at least to test the theory.